# pg_restore ignores .pgpass and PGPASSWORD environment variable

Tags: bash, postgresql, pg-restore

I want to import a backup using pg_restore without a password prompt.
I tried several options but after I run the script it will always ask for a password. pg_dump is working but not pg_restore. I can run the pg_restore command if I enter my password but I want a passwordless command or at least I don't want to enter my password because the script has to work without user interaction.

What is working for me:

```
 PGPASSWORD=xyz pg_dump -h localhost -U user -Fc database > ~/dump_prod.pgsql
```

What is NOT working

1.)

```
PGPASSWORD=xyz pg_restore -h localhost -d database -U user -W --clean --no-owner ~/dump_prod.pgsql
```

2.)

```
pg_restore --dbname=postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/db -W --clean --no-owner ~/dump_prod.pgsql
```

3.)

```
touch ~/.pgpass
echo "*:*:*:*:password > ~/.pgpass
chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass
pg_restore -h localhost -d db -U user -W --clean --no-owner ~/dump_prod.pgsql
```

any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgrestore.html), `-W` will prompt for a password. `-w` will not

> -w
>   --no-password
>
> Never issue a password prompt. If the server requires password authentication and a password is not available by other means such as
>   a .pgpass file, the connection attempt will fail. This option can be
>   useful in batch jobs and scripts where no user is present to enter a
>   password.
>
> -W
>   --password
>
> Force pg_restore to prompt for a password before connecting to a database.

Answer (score 0):

The `.pgpass` file worked for me.

My setup:
I am restoring DB into the postgres instance running as Docker container.

The postgres instance is run using command:

```sh
docker run --name postgres_db -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin -d postgres:9.6
```

`pg_restore` is present but it is available as separate tool, outside docker setup.

The `~/.pgpass` file entry looks like this:

`localhost:5432:db_name:user:password`

Where:

**db_name** is the target db name that one is going to restore.

**user** is the name of the user that is going to perform the restore - in my case an admin user. i.e. *postgres* user in the postgres instance.

**password** - admin user's password. i.e. *admin*